# Firestore setDoc() method somehow generates a unique identifier when doc says it won't

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[Google documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) states that

> When you use set() to create a document, you must specify an ID

However, I just learned that I CAN call `setDoc` without specifying the ID like this, and it will still generate a unique identifier.

```js
await setDoc(doc(collctionRef), {
        createdAt: new Date(),
        updatedAt: new Date(),
      });
```

### Question

1. Is the Firebase documentation outdated? or is there something I missed?
2. If this is true, `addDoc` seems useless now. Or is there another use for it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify document ID in `doc(collctionRef)` then it'll generate one automatically. The same was in previous SDK:

```
// This would add a Document with random ID

// V8
colRef.doc().set({})

// V9
setDoc(doc(colRef))
```

From the same documentation,

> Behind the scenes, `.add(...)` and `.doc().set(...)` are completely equivalent, so you can use whichever is more convenient.

Comment: I missed that part! Huh, so they are the same. Kind of weird that they say you "must" specify the ID then.

Comment: It's more like you must specify an ID if you want a custom ID because `.doc()` would return a DocRef with a random ID anyways.

Comment: Assuming that your `collctionRef` is a `CollectionReference`, calling `doc(collctionRef)` generates a `DocumentReference` with an ID already. So as far as `setDoc` is concerned, you're passing it the required document ID.

Comment: So that's something the SDK does internally.